# Lightweight Groovy persistence

Tags: database, groovy, persistence

What are some lightweight options for persistence in Groovy? I've considered serialization and XML so far but I want something a bit more robust than those, at least so I don't have to rewrite the entire file every time. Ideally, it would:

- Require no JARs in classpath, using Grapes instead
- Require no external processes, administration, or authentication (so all embedded)
- Support locking

I plan on using it to cache some information between runs of a standalone Groovy script. I imagine responses will focus around SQL and NoSQL databases. Links to pages demonstrating this usage would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Full SQL Database

The [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) in-process SQL database is very easy to use.  This is the same database engine grails uses by default, but it's simple to use in a groovy script as well:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab(group='com.h2database', module='h2', version='1.3.167')

import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:h2:hello", "sa", "sa", "org.h2.Driver")
sql.execute("create table test (id int, value text)")
sql.execute("insert into test values(:id, :value)", [id: 1, value: 'hello'])
println sql.rows("select * from test")
```

In this case the database will be saved to a file called `hello.h2.db`.

## Simple Persistent Maps

Another alternative is [jdbm](https://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/), which provides disk-backed persistent maps.  Internally, it uses Java's serialization.  The programming interface is much simpler, but it's also much less powerful than a full-blown SQL db.  There's no support for concurrent access, but it is synchronized and thread safe, which may be enough depending on your locking requirements.  Here's a simple example:

```
@Grab(group='org.fusesource.jdbm', module='jdbm', version='2.0.1')

import jdbm.*

def recMan = RecordManagerFactory.createRecordManager('hello')
def treeMap = recMan.treeMap("test")
treeMap[1] = 'hello'
treeMap[100] = 'goodbye'
recMan.commit()
println treeMap
```

This will save the map to a set of files.

Answer (score 7):

just a little groovy update on simple persistence using JDBM. Concurrent access is supported now. Name has changed from JDBM4 to MapDB.

```
@Grab(group='org.mapdb', module='mapdb', version='0.9.3')

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentNavigableMap
import org.mapdb.*

DB db = DBMaker.newFileDB( new File("myDB.file") )
           .closeOnJvmShutdown()
           .make()

ConcurrentNavigableMap<String,String> map = db.getTreeMap("myMap")

map.put("1", "one")
map.put("2", "two")
db.commit()

println "keySet "+map.keySet()

assert map.get("1") == "one"
assert map.get("2") == "two"

db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) is a persisted `ConcurrentMap` implementation for JVM.

Usage example:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, String> store = ChronicleMap
    .of(String.class, String.class)
    .averageKey("cachedKey").averageValue("cachedValue")
    .entries(10_000)
    .createPersistedTo(new File("cacheFile"))

store.put("foo", "bar")
store.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am little late to the party. But for sake of posterity, listing one more options here:

[gstorm](https://github.com/kdabir/gstorm/)

> A simple ORM for databases and CSV files. Intended to be used in groovy scripts and small projects

*disclosure: author here :)*